# Is there a way to clone my character profile in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to create multiple variants of my character in [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) but I don't want to have to manually re-create basic attributes such as:

- Eyes
- Hair
- Mouth
- Height

I'd like to clone my character profile from one slot to a newly created profile:

[image: Screenshot of the character profile creation slider.]

I found the user data file that retains the profiles at the [standard data path](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360035131551-Where-are-Minecraft-Files-Stored-):

```
C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\
```

My file was named `ud2609080963` but yours may be different. Inside, I found `JSON` data that represented my characters, and I wanted to copy `personaProfile5` to `personaProfile4`. In the case of the screenshot above, it would copy the attributes of the character on the right, to the character on the left.

After copying the data from `personaProfile5` to `personaProfile4` and launching [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition), to no surprise, the file was overwritten and the old basic Steve was still there.

I tried changing it during runtime too but that also didn't work. What *seems* to be happening, is that the file is overwritten *after* the user profile is loaded on launch.

I've spent too much time trying to figure this out at this point (could've created all five characters manually by now, and then some). So I'm going to give up for now and pose the question to the community.

---

Is there a way to clone at least the basic attributes of one character profile to another?